# How to get the changes between two strings (insertion, deletion or same)?

Tags: javascript, c#, algorithm, levenshtein-distance

I used implementation of `Levenshtein` algorithm to get the distance between two strings, but what I really need is where (the indexes) in the second string happened insertion or deletion or stayed the same ?
Is there any implementation to do this in JavaScript (or other C#)?

Comment: Did you actually search, there are plenty of libraries that do it. Google has a "diff match patch" library that works in multiple languages.

Comment: Thanks a lot @epascarello please add the comment as answer so I can mark it.

Comment: I had done an efficient [`String.prototype.diff()`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/133849/105433) implementation in JS sometime ago. It might give you an idea. It's done by rotating the strings and handles large paragraphs in a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Google offers Diff Match and Patch libraries that contains robust algorithms to perform the tasks you asked for. These libraries can be used in Java, JavaScript, Python, C++, C#, Objective-C, Lua and Dart.

1. **Diff:** Diff takes two texts and finds the differences. This implementation works on a character by character basis. The result of any diff may contain 'chaff', irrelevant small commonalities which complicate the output. A post-diff cleanup algorithm factors out these trivial commonalities.
2. **Match:** Match looks for a pattern within a larger text. This implementation of match is fuzzy, meaning it can find a match even if the pattern contains errors and doesn't exactly match what is found in the text. This implementation also accepts an expected location, near which the match should be found. The candidate matches are scored based on a) the number of spelling differences between the pattern and the text and b) the distance between the candidate match and the expected location. The match distance parameter sets the relative importance of these two metrics.
3. **Patch:** Two texts can be diff-ed against each other, generating a list of patches. These patches can then be applied against a third text. If the third text has edits of its own, this version of patch will apply its changes on a best-effort basis, reporting which patches succeeded and which failed.

You can learn more about it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/).